# Preventing NaN when the value is equal to zero

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to make a converter web app that displays the converted value on an input. After clearing the input field to type another value, my input fields return NaN. My goal is to set the values to zero after clearing a particular input field (could be Celsius, Fahrenheit, and Kelvin field).

**temperature.html**

```
<main role="main" class="container">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card mt-4">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h1 class="text-center">Temperature</h1>
            <div class="row mt-4 justify-content-center">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Celsius (°C)</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="celsius" oninput="celToFar()" placeholder="Enter value">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Fahrenheit (°F)</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fahrenheit" oninput="farToCel()" placeholder="Enter value">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Kelvin (K)</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="kelvin" oninput="KelToCel()" placeholder="Enter value">
                </div>
               </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

**app.js**

```
const celsius = document.getElementById('celsius');
const fahrenheit = document.getElementById('fahrenheit');
const kelvin = document.getElementById('kelvin');



function celToFar() {

    // celsius to fahrenheit
    let output = ( parseFloat(celsius.value) * 9/5) + 32;
    fahrenheit.value = parseFloat(output.toFixed(2));

    // celsius to kelvin
    let output2 = ( parseFloat(celsius.value) + 273.15);
    kelvin.value = parseFloat(output2.toFixed(2));

}

function farToCel() {

    // fahrenheit to celsius
    let output = ( parseFloat(fahrenheit.value) - 32) * 5/9;
    celsius.value = parseFloat(output.toFixed(2));

    // fahrenheit to kelvin
    let output2 = ( parseFloat(fahrenheit.value) - 32) * 5/9 + 273.15;
    kelvin.value = parseFloat(output2.toFixed(2));
    
}


// New vals

function KelToCel() {

    // kelvin to celsius
    let output = ( parseFloat(kelvin.value) - 273.15);
    celsius.value = parseFloat(output.toFixed(2));

    // kelvin to fahrenheit
    let output2 = ( parseFloat(kelvin.value) - 273.15) * 9/5 + 32;
    fahrenheit.value = parseFloat(output2.toFixed(2));


}
```

Comment: u can use isNaN which returns boolean to check the validity of the value and do things according to the result

Comment: ( parseFloat(celsius.value) * 9/5) + 32 || 0     .You can set 0 like this when result is NaN.

Answer (score 0):

`value || 0` should help

```js
const celsius = document.getElementById('celsius');
const fahrenheit = document.getElementById('fahrenheit');
const kelvin = document.getElementById('kelvin');


function celToFar() {

    // celsius to fahrenheit
    let output = ( parseFloat(celsius.value || 0) * 9/5) + 32;
    fahrenheit.value = parseFloat(output.toFixed(2));

    // celsius to kelvin
    let output2 = ( parseFloat(celsius.value || 0) + 273.15);
    kelvin.value = parseFloat(output2.toFixed(2));

}

function farToCel() {

    // fahrenheit to celsius
    let output = ( parseFloat(fahrenheit.value || 0) - 32) * 5/9;
    celsius.value = parseFloat(output.toFixed(2));

    // fahrenheit to kelvin
    let output2 = ( parseFloat(fahrenheit.value || 0) - 32) * 5/9 + 273.15;
    kelvin.value = parseFloat(output2.toFixed(2));
    
}
```

```html
<main role="main" class="container">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card mt-4">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h1 class="text-center">Temperature</h1>
            <div class="row mt-4 justify-content-center">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Celsius (°C)</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="celsius" oninput="celToFar()" placeholder="Enter value">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Fahrenheit (°F)</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fahrenheit" oninput="farToCel()" placeholder="Enter value">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Kelvin (K)</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="kelvin" oninput="KelToCel()" placeholder="Enter value">
                </div>
               </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```